# This method must return a result of type boolean(Java)

Tags: java, return, boolean, return-value, return-type

this is my code.

```
boolean checkHit2() {
    if (cx < 0 || cx >= 640) {return true;}
    if (cy < ground[(int)cx]) {return false;}
    if (cx < blue + 15 && cx > blue - 15) {
        score = (int)score + 1;
```

What am I doing wrong? it gives me the error message "This method must return a result of type boolean". Please help.

Comment: This code won't even _compile_.  Can you repost the full method?

Comment: Of course it doesn't compile, that's what the OP is asking, why does s/he get the error "This method must return a result of type boolean" when s/he tries to compile it.

Answer (score 2):

> "This method must return a result of type boolean"

Means your method should return the `boolean` value for *every case*. Currently it will return `boolean` if one of your if condition is `true`. What about if none of your if condition is `true`? In this case compiler will not be able to return anything to the caller of the method. So that compiler is telling you to add a `return` statement for method for every case no matter condition satisfy or not. You should add `return false` at the end of the method.

Answer (score 1):

In your method you must `return` a variable in each case (for each `if` statement), in this case, a boolean.

Example:

```
boolean checkHit2() {

  if (cx < 0 || cx >= 640) {return true;}
  if (cy < ground[(int)cx]) {return false;}
if (cx < blue + 15 && cx > blue - 15){
  score = (int)score + 1;
  return false;
}
```

Also, just to clean up your code a bit, the curly brackets are unneeded if the contents of the block is only one line. For example you can use:

```
boolean checkHit2() {

  if (cx < 0 || cx >= 640) return true;
  if (cy < ground[(int)cx]) return false;
if (cx < blue + 15 && cx > blue - 15){
  score = (int)score + 1;
  return false;
}
```

Functionally, they act the same. It's just a useful shortcut to clean up your code :).

In this example i simply returned false because i'm insure of the functionality of your program or how you would like it to work. You could return a value based on a `if` or `else` statement, etc. but it's up to you and what you want your program to do.

To see more about `return`, [click here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Answer (score -1):

This line:

```
<b>if (cx < blue + 15 && cx > blue - 15){ </b>
```

Should be changed to

```
<b>if((cx < (blue + 15)) && (cx > (blue -15))){</b>
```

but I think you should move the comparation out like:

```
int bluePlus = blue + 15;
int blueMinus = blue - 15;
if(cx < bluePlus && cx > blueMinus){
```

EDIT:
The error means that you miss to return boolean after all. After the if

```
if(cx < bluePlus && cx > blueMinus){
```

then you need to add return to the result.
Please ignore the first comment.

Comment: This answer is simply invalid. It doesn't address the error thrown at all.